# Apply gamma correction to packed integer pixel

Tags: java, image, graphics, rendering, pixel

I'm trying to add Gamma correction to my rendering engine. I have two problems:

1)  Math.pow is REALLY slow (relative to being called thousands of times per second). So I will need to create a precalculated gamma table that can be accessed instead of calculating on the fly. (This is extra information, not the actual problem).

2) Currently, I can only do this by unpacking the integer pixels, applying the gamma through replacing the RGBA channels with their corresponding gamma modified values, and then repacking the pixels and sending it back to the image buffer. The performance hit isn't *terrible...*  but it is knocking a solid 60fps fixed timestep down to around 40fps or so (with several images being rendered).

I tried implementing the integer unpacking/packing in native code, only to see no performance improvement and get VM crashing (probably memory checking errors but I don't really care to fix it now).

Is there a way to apply the gamma without unpacking/packing pixels? If not, what method would you recommend using to do this?

N.B. Don't say use BufferedImageOp. It's slow and can only operate on the entire image (I need pixel specific).

**Additional Info:**

Pixel packaging:

```
public static int[] unpackInt(int argb, int type) {
    int[] vals = null;
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 1;
    int p3 = 2;
    int p4 = 3;
    switch (type) {
    case TYPE_RGB:
        vals = new int[3];
        vals[p1] = argb >> 16 & 0xFF;
        vals[p2] = argb >> 8 & 0xFF;
        vals[p3] = argb & 0xFF;
        break;
    case TYPE_RGBA:
    case TYPE_ARGB:
        vals = new int[4];
        vals[p4] = argb & 0xFF;
        vals[p3] = argb >> 8 & 0xFF;
        vals[p2] = argb >> 16 & 0xFF;
        vals[p1] = argb >> 24 & 0xFF;
        break;
    default:
        throw (new IllegalArgumentException(
                "type must be a valid field defined by ColorUtils class"));
    }
    return vals;
}

public static int packInt(int... rgbs) {

    if (rgbs.length != 3 && rgbs.length != 4) {
        throw (new IllegalArgumentException(
                "args must be valid RGB, ARGB or RGBA value."));
    }
    int color = rgbs[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < rgbs.length; i++) {
        color = (color << 8) + rgbs[i];
    }
    return color;
}
```

I scrapped the code previously, but I was using this algorithm for gamma correction:

```
protected int correctGamma(int pixel, float gamma) {
    float ginv = 1 / gamma;
    int[] rgbVals = ColorUtils.unpackInt(pixel, ColorUtils.TYPE_ARGB);
    for(int i = 0; i < rgbVals.length; i++) {
        rgbVals[i] = (int) Math.round(255 - Math.pow(rgbVals[i] / 255.0, ginv));
    }
    return ColorUtils.packInt(rgbVals);
}
```

**Solution**

I ended up combining a lot of the ideas GargantuChet proposed into a system that seems to work fairly well (no drop in performance).

A class called GammaTable is instantiated with a gamma value modifier (0.0-1.0 is darker and >1.0 is brighter).  The constructor calls an internal method that builds the gamma table for this value.  This method is also used for resetting gamma later:

```
/**
 * Called when a new gamma value is set to rebuild the gamma table.
 */
private synchronized void buildGammaTable() {
    table = new int[TABLE_SIZE];
    float ginv = 1 / gamma;
    double colors = COLORS;
    for(int i=0;i<table.length;i++) {
        table[i] = (int) Math.round(colors * Math.pow(i / colors, ginv)); 
    }
}
```

To apply the gamma, GammaTable takes an integer pixel, unpacks it, looks up the modified gamma values, and returns the repacked integer*

```
/**
 * Applies the current gamma table to the given integer pixel.
 * @param color the integer pixel to which gamma will be applied
 * @param type a pixel type defined by ColorUtils
 * @param rgbArr optional pre-instantiated array to use when unpacking.  May be null.
 * @return the modified pixel value
 */
public int applyGamma(int color, int type, int[] rgbArr) {
    int[] argb = (rgbArr != null) ? ColorUtils.unpackInt(rgbArr, color):ColorUtils.unpackInt(color, type);
    for(int i = 0; i < argb.length; i++) {
        int col = argb[i];
        argb[i] = table[col];
    }
    int newColor = ColorUtils.packInt(argb);
    return newColor;
}
```

The `applyGamma` method is called for each pixel on screen.

*As it turns out, unpacking and repackaging the pixels wasn't slowing anything down.  For some reason, nesting the calls (i.e. `ColorUtils.packInt(ColorUtils.unpackInt))` caused the method to take substantially longer.  Interestingly enough, I also had to stop using a pre-instantiated array with `ColorUtils.unpackInt` because it seemed to be causing a huge performance hit.  Allowing the unpacking method to create a new array with each call does not seem to affect performance in the current context.

Comment: +1, interesting question. Might you show some code to demonstrate how you're unpacking/processing/repacking? Also, this is as much out of curiosity as anything, how are you calculating your gamma values?

Comment: I will update the post with both pieces of information.  Thanks for inquiring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder whether it's the math operations that are causing the overhead. With each call to unpackInt you're creating a new array, which the JVM has to allocate and initialize to zeros. This could be causing a lot of heap activity that really isn't needed.

You might consider an approach where unpackInt takes the destination array as a parameter. As a first pass, the usage example would look like

```
int[] rgbVals = new int[4];

protected int correctGamma(int pixel, float gamma) {
    float ginv = 1 / gamma;
    ColorUtils.unpackInt(pixel, ColorUtils.TYPE_ARGB, rgbVals);
    for(int i = 0; i &lt; rgbVals.length; i++) {
        rgbVals[i] = (int) Math.round(255 - Math.pow(rgbVals[i] / 255.0, ginv));
    }
    return ColorUtils.packInt(rgbVals);
}
```

This would really reduce the object-creation overhead as you would create the new array only once, instead of once per call to unpackInt (via correctGamma). The only caveat is that you could no longer use array length when repacking the int. This could be solved easily enough by passing type to it as a parameter as well, or by setting the unused element to 0 in the TYPE_RGB case in unpackInt:

```
case TYPE_RGB:
    vals[p1] = 0;
    vals[p2] = argb >> 16 & 0xFF;
    vals[p3] = argb >> 8 & 0xFF;
    vals[p4] = argb & 0xFF;
```

This might also be a good opportunity to create a more specialized class for gamma correction, which encapsulates all of this behavior:

```
class ScreenContent {

    // ...

    GammaCorrector gammaCorrector = new GammaCorrector();

    // ...

    int[][] image;

    void correctGamma() {
        for (int[] row : image) {
            for (int i = 0; i &lt; row.length; i++) {
                row[i] = gammaCorrector.correct(row[i], gamma);
            }
        }
    }
}

class GammaCorrector {
    private int[] unpacked = new int[4];

    public int correct(int pixel, float gamma) {
        float ginv = 1 / gamma;
        ColorUtils.unpackInt(pixel, ColorUtils.TYPE_ARGB, unpacked);
        for(int i = 0; i &lt; rgbVals.length; i++) {
            rgbVals[i] = (int) Math.round(255 - Math.pow(unpacked[i] / 255.0, ginv));
        }
        return ColorUtils.packInt(unpacked);
    }
}
```

You could eliminate the array and loops by making a `struct`-like class to hold the unpacked values. The innermost `for()` loop is executed hundreds of thousands of times per second, but each time the loop is executed it runs for only a few iterations. A modern CPU [should handle this case very well](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/branch-and-loop-reorganization-to-prevent-mispredicts) but it still may be worth trying.

You could also use a bounded thread pool to image rows in parallel. A bound of one thread per CPU core might make sense. Graphics hardware design focuses on the fact that operations on each pixel are typically similar but independent, and they massive parallelism to achieve good performance.

Also consider [using a debug build of the JVM](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2008/03/deep_dive_into.html) to look at the generated instructions for better insight. Ideally you'd modify your code as little as possible, only making changes where the JVM missed opportunities for optimization.

If you end up going toward native code, you might look into using some of the SSE instructions where appropriate. I believe there are operations that work on packed integers, basically applying the same operation to each byte in a packed integer without having to unpack, calculate, and repack. That could save a good amount of time but might involve changes to the way you're calculating gamma. The upside is that it's quick -- a single SSE register can let you operate on sixteen bytes in a single instruction, and that sort of parallelism can be worth taking the effort to exploit.

Comment: I will try some of these suggestions and let you know how they work out.  Would the array instantiation really cause that much overhead?

Comment: Ok so, using the fixed array instead of instantiation brought the FPS back up to 50 (just unpacking and repackaging the int... no gamma correction lookup or application).  That's still a 10fps hit.

Would it help to put the fixed array in native code?  That could potentially remove the Java array-checking overhead right?

Comment: To respond to your first question, modern JVMs do a good job of optimizing the creation of lots of small objects in the general case. But here the operation is done for each pixel. With a low resolution like 1024*768, that means 786,432 array creations per frame, or 47,185,920 pixel operations per second @ 60 fps. On a 2GHz CPU, you'd have to average better than about 42 instructions per pixel to make that frame rate. So every small bit helps.

Comment: Updated the answer with some more thoughts.

Comment: So have a thread working on every row of the image, then use a CyclicBarrier to prevent the rendering thread from drawing the image until they are done?

Comment: Or a Future object, I suppose.

Comment: I tried using the multi-threaded row copying approach.  It does work, and it is significantly faster with straight rendering.  However, when I add the ColorUtils.packInt(ColorUtils.unpackInt)) to the rendering row loop, it gets actually WORSE FPS than before (~40).

Comment: Wow, that's unexpected. Be sure you're not using `synchronized` unnecessarily. Also, does each thread get its own `int[]` for storing unpacked values? If not, maybe there's contention between threads for the shared array.

Comment: For some reason, the performance drop goes away if you don't nest the call in the argument spot (i.e. ColorUTils.packInt(ColorUtils.unpackInt)), it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to use OpenGL. (I think LWJGL would allow it in Java.) You could upload a 1D texture containing the straight to gamma corrected table, and then write a glsl shader that applied the gamma table to your pixels. Not sure how that would fit in with your current processing model, but I use it to process 1920x1080 HD RGBA frames in real-time all the time.

Comment: That's brilliant. You should really consider choosing a username :-)

Comment: That's an interesting idea... however I've been trying to avoid additional libraries in the project (and use only Java2D... a pain but useful for many things).  I also have absolutely zero experience writing shaders of any kind or using OpenGL/LWJGL for any significant projects.